# Проверка пользователя в БД Postgrsql на Node.js

Tags: node.js

Не получатся проверить **email** пользователя в БД, точнее проверка проходит а вот на то что есть или нету **email** в БД не получается. **rows** возвращается а вот что делать дальше не разберусь. Пишу цикл для запроса, БД зависает. При ответе что есть email нужно не регистрировать пользователя а при отрицательном ответе пользователя нужно зарегистрировать. Node.js Тот код который закомментирован это регистрация пользователя. Благодарен за любую помощь.

Вот мой код:

```
const db = require('../db')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
//const { json } = require('express')

class userController {
    async createUser  (req, res) {
        try{

            const {name, surname, email, pass, pass2} = req.body

               db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1', [email] , (err, row) =>{

                if(err){
                    console.log('Error executing query', err.stack);
                }
                //res.json(row)
                let isTrue=false
                if(row){
                    for(let i=0; i < row.length; i++){
                        if(row[i].email == email){
                            isTrue = true;
                            row.json({"message": "C данным email пользователь есть"})
                        }else{
                            row.json({"message": " Регистрирую пользователя"})
                        }
                    }
                }
                
              });

              
            
                /*if(pass==pass2){
                    const hashPass = bcrypt.hashSync(pass, 15)
                    const hashPass2 = bcrypt.hashSync(pass2, 15)
        
                    const newPerson = await db.query(`INSERT INTO users(name, surname, email, pass, pass2) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING *`, [name, surname, email, hashPass, hashPass2])
                    res.json(newPerson.rows)
                }else{
                    res.json({"message" : "пароли не совпадают"})
                }*/
            

        } catch(e){
            console.log(e)
            res.send({message: "Server error"})

        }
        

    }
```

Вот что возвращает сервер res.json(row):

```
{
    "command": "SELECT",
    "rowCount": 0,
    "oid": null,
    "rows": [],
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "id",
            "tableID": 16420,
            "columnID": 1,
            "dataTypeID": 23,
            "dataTypeSize": 4,
            "dataTypeModifier": -1,
            "format": "text"
        },
        {
            "name": "name",
            "tableID": 16420,
            "columnID": 2,
            "dataTypeID": 1043,
            "dataTypeSize": -1,
            "dataTypeModifier": 259,
            "format": "text"
        },
        {
            "name": "surname",
            "tableID": 16420,
            "columnID": 3,
            "dataTypeID": 1043,
            "dataTypeSize": -1,
            "dataTypeModifier": 259,
            "format": "text"
        },
        {
            "name": "email",
            "tableID": 16420,
            "columnID": 4,
            "dataTypeID": 1043,
            "dataTypeSize": -1,
            "dataTypeModifier": 259,
            "format": "text"
        },
        {
            "name": "pass",
            "tableID": 16420,
            "columnID": 5,
            "dataTypeID": 1043,
            "dataTypeSize": -1,
            "dataTypeModifier": 259,
            "format": "text"
        },
        {
            "name": "pass2",
            "tableID": 16420,
            "columnID": 6,
            "dataTypeID": 1043,
            "dataTypeSize": -1,
            "dataTypeModifier": 259,
            "format": "text"
        }
    ],
    "_parsers": [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
    ],
    "_types": {
        "_types": {
            "arrayParser": {},
            "builtins": {
                "BOOL": 16,
                "BYTEA": 17,
                "CHAR": 18,
                "INT8": 20,
                "INT2": 21,
                "INT4": 23,
                "REGPROC": 24,
                "TEXT": 25,
                "OID": 26,
                "TID": 27,
                "XID": 28,
                "CID": 29,
                "JSON": 114,
                "XML": 142,
                "PG_NODE_TREE": 194,
                "SMGR": 210,
                "PATH": 602,
                "POLYGON": 604,
                "CIDR": 650,
                "FLOAT4": 700,
                "FLOAT8": 701,
                "ABSTIME": 702,
                "RELTIME": 703,
                "TINTERVAL": 704,
                "CIRCLE": 718,
                "MACADDR8": 774,
                "MONEY": 790,
                "MACADDR": 829,
                "INET": 869,
                "ACLITEM": 1033,
                "BPCHAR": 1042,
                "VARCHAR": 1043,
                "DATE": 1082,
                "TIME": 1083,
                "TIMESTAMP": 1114,
                "TIMESTAMPTZ": 1184,
                "INTERVAL": 1186,
                "TIMETZ": 1266,
                "BIT": 1560,
                "VARBIT": 1562,
                "NUMERIC": 1700,
                "REFCURSOR": 1790,
                "REGPROCEDURE": 2202,
                "REGOPER": 2203,
                "REGOPERATOR": 2204,
                "REGCLASS": 2205,
                "REGTYPE": 2206,
                "UUID": 2950,
                "TXID_SNAPSHOT": 2970,
                "PG_LSN": 3220,
                "PG_NDISTINCT": 3361,
                "PG_DEPENDENCIES": 3402,
                "TSVECTOR": 3614,
                "TSQUERY": 3615,
                "GTSVECTOR": 3642,
                "REGCONFIG": 3734,
                "REGDICTIONARY": 3769,
                "JSONB": 3802,
                "REGNAMESPACE": 4089,
                "REGROLE": 4096
            }
        },
        "text": {},
        "binary": {}
    },
    "RowCtor": null,
    "rowAsArray": false
}
```

А это возвращает console.log(row);

```
Result {
  command: 'SELECT',
  rowCount: 0,
  oid: null,
  rows: [],
  fields: [
    Field {
      name: 'id',
      tableID: 16420,
      columnID: 1,
      dataTypeID: 23,
      dataTypeSize: 4,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      format: 'text'
    },
    Field {
      name: 'name',
      tableID: 16420,
      columnID: 2,
      dataTypeID: 1043,
      dataTypeSize: -1,
      dataTypeModifier: 259,
      format: 'text'
    },
    Field {
      name: 'surname',
      tableID: 16420,
      columnID: 3,
      dataTypeID: 1043,
      dataTypeSize: -1,
      dataTypeModifier: 259,
      format: 'text'
    },
    Field {
      name: 'email',
      tableID: 16420,
      columnID: 4,
      dataTypeID: 1043,
      dataTypeSize: -1,
      dataTypeModifier: 259,
      format: 'text'
    },
    Field {
      name: 'pass',
      tableID: 16420,
      columnID: 5,
      dataTypeID: 1043,
      dataTypeSize: -1,
      dataTypeModifier: 259,
      format: 'text'
    },
    Field {
      name: 'pass2',
      tableID: 16420,
      columnID: 6,
      dataTypeID: 1043,
      dataTypeSize: -1,
      dataTypeModifier: 259,
      format: 'text'
    }
  ],
  _parsers: [
    [Function: parseInteger],
    [Function: noParse],
    [Function: noParse],
    [Function: noParse],
    [Function: noParse],
    [Function: noParse]
  ],
  _types: TypeOverrides {
    _types: {
      getTypeParser: [Function: getTypeParser],
      setTypeParser: [Function: setTypeParser],
      arrayParser: [Object],
      builtins: [Object]
    },
    text: {},
    binary: {}
  },
  RowCtor: null,
  rowAsArray: false
}
```

А как вывести в формате json после регистрации. Вот код:

```
const newPerson  = db.query('INSERT INTO users(name, surname, email, pass, pass2) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING *', [name, surname, email, hashPass, hashPass2])
                    res.json(newPerson.rows)
```

Так как возвращает 1

Comment: По хорошему, запрос должен возвращать только одну строку или ничего. Пробовали в консоль выводить то, что сервер вам возвращает? Можете показать console.log(row)

Comment: Да я возвращал row. Как мне вывеси например row.email. или сделать if на сравнение есть или нету такого email. Там где цикл for там был console.log(row).  Мне нужна там проверка на то что там есть или нету email.

Comment: Добавь сюда вывод консоли row. Без понимания структуры, которая приходит из БД сложно дать ответ

Comment: Я вас понял. Добавлю вывод row из БД.

Comment: Я добавил вывод консоли row.

Comment: у вас row это объект. В нем есть ключ rows и он пуст - из бд ни одной записи не вернулось. Об этом вам даже в ответе сообщено `rowCount: 0`

Comment: А есть варианта как должно быть правильно?

Comment: Я извиняюсь, я еще написал один вопрос.

Comment: При запросе без if возвращает весь json , а вот в if возвращает 1

Comment: Оформи это отдельным постом и приложи туда код и результаты, которые приходят.
Не видя данные, которые возвращаются, сложно давать советы

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо вот так переделать проверку

```
if (row.rowCount) {
  for (let i = 0; i < row.rows.length; i++) {
    if (row.rows[i].email === email) {
      isTrue = true;
      break;
    }
  }
}
if (isTrue) {
  row.json({"message": "C данным email пользователь есть"})
} else {
  row.json({"message": " Регистрирую пользователя"})
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! А с запросом все правильно?

Comment: Визуально да. Попробуйте сам текст запроса собрать в строку и вывести в консоль. Подозреваю, что вам надо переписать запрос вот так `'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ''$1'''` т.к. email это текстовое поле

Comment: Спасибо Вам SwaD! Весь код который вы мне передали сработал. Только в запросе сделал вот так:

Comment: 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1::text'

Comment: Ну с postgree не работал и не знаю, какой библиотекой вы пользуетесь для для доступа к БД. Если все хорошо, жмите галочку - принять ответ )

Comment: Я извиняюсь, я еще написал один вопрос. Где эта галочка? Библиотека pg.

Comment: Я создал новый вопрос "При регистрации не возвращается json Node.js"

Comment: Должна быть слева от ответа. Там 0 стоит, две стрелки вверх вниз и ниже должна быть галочка